# Chaining mysqldumps commands to output a single gzipped file

Tags: command-line, io-redirection, gzip, dump

Let's say I have these series of commands

```
mysqldump --opt --databases $dbname1 --host=$dbhost1 --user=$dbuser1 --password=$dbpass1
mysqldump --opt --databases $dbname2 --host=$dbhost1 --user=$dbuser1 --password=$dbpass1
mysqldump --opt --databases $dbname3 --host=$dbhost2 --user=$dbuser2 --password=$dbpass2
mysqldump --opt --databases $dbname4 --host=$dbhost2 --user=$dbuser2 --password=$dbpass2
```

How do put all their outputs(assuming that the output name is $dbhost.$dbname.sql) and put it inside one file named backupfile.sql.gz using only one line of code?

**Edit**: From comments to answers below, @arvinsim actually wants a compressed **archive** file containing the SQL dumps in separate files, not *one* compressed SQL file.

Comment: I think you should change at least the title of your question to make clear you don't want to chain the output of the commands, just the commands.

Comment: @Anthon I updated the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment to @tink's answer you want seperate files in the `.gz` files:

```
mysqldump --opt --databases $dbname1 --host=$dbhost1 --user=$dbuser1 --password=$dbpass1 > '/var/tmp/$dbhost1.$dbname1.sql' ; mysqldump --opt --databases $dbname2 --host=$dbhost1 --user=$dbuser1 --password=$dbpass1 > '/var/tmp/$dbhost1.$dbname2.sql' ; mysqldump --opt --databases $dbname3 --host=$dbhost2 --user=$dbuser2 --password=$dbpass2 > '/var/tmp/$dbhost1.$dbname3.sql' ; mysqldump --opt --databases $dbname4 --host=$dbhost2 --user=$dbuser2 --password=$dbpass2 > '/var/tmp/$dbhost1.$dbname4.sql' ; cd /var/tmp; tar cvzf backupfile.sql.gz \$dbhost1.\$dbname*.sql
```

- As an alternative for the output filename I would use `backupfile.sql.tgz` so it is more clear to experienced users this is a tar file that is compressed
- You can append `rm \$dbhost1.\$dbname*.sql` to get rid of the intermediate files
- You could use `zip` as alternative to compressed tar.
- I am not sure why you want this as a one-liner. If you just want to issue one command you should put the lines in script and excute from there.
- With the 'normal' tools used for something like this (`tar`, `zip`), I am not aware of circumventing the intermediate files.

**Addendum**

If you really do not want intermediate files (and assuming the output fits in memory) you could try something like the following Python program. You can write this as a oneliner ( `python -c "from subprocess import checkout; from cStr....`), but I really do not recommend that.

```
from subprocess import check_output
from cStringIO import StringIO
import tarfile

outputdata = [
    ('$dbhost1.$dbname1.sql', '$dbname1'),
    ('$dbhost1.$dbname2.sql', '$dbname2'),
    ('$dbhost1.$dbname3.sql', '$dbname3'),
    ('$dbhost1.$dbname4.sql', '$dbname4'),
]

with tarfile.open('/var/tmp/backupfile.sql.tgz', 'w:gz') as tgz:
    for outname, db in outputdata:
        cmd = ['mysqldump', '--opt', '--databases']
        cmd.append(db)
        cmd.extend(['--host=$dbhost1', '--user=$dbuser1', '--password=$dbpass1'])
        out = check_output(cmd)
        buf = StringIO(out)
        buf.seek(0)
        tarinfo = tarfile.TarInfo(name=outname)
        tarinfo.size = len(out)
        tgz.addfile(tarinfo=tarinfo, fileobj=buf)
```

Depending on how regular your database and 'output' names are you can further improve on that.

Comment: I'm not finding a way to do it without the intermediate files either.

Comment: I see, so basically this intermediate file feature is probably not supported then. I just wanted to avoid creating files because the script's output is not always going to be the same as the present working directory and the script may not have permission to output in present working directory.

Comment: Do you mean do it without an intermediate file? If that's what you're asking I think the answer is no.

Comment: @arvinsim I changed the oneliner to write in `/var/tmp` (both the intermediate files and the final output `.tgz`).

Comment: @slm I agree on the 'no' without intermediate filename for the regular ('tar', 'zip') tools, with some programming it can however be done relatively easily.

Comment: @Anthon, Yes agreed.

Answer (score 3):

```
( mysqldump --opt --databases $dbname1 --host=$dbhost1 --user=$dbuser1 --password=$dbpass1; \
  mysqldump --opt --databases $dbname2 --host=$dbhost1 --user=$dbuser1 --password=$dbpass1; \
  mysqldump --opt --databases $dbname3 --host=$dbhost2 --user=$dbuser2 --password=$dbpass2; \
  mysqldump --opt --databases $dbname4 --host=$dbhost2 --user=$dbuser2 --password=$dbp \
 ) | gzip > backupfile.sql.gz
```

Or as one line:

```
( mysqldump --opt --databases $dbname1 --host=$dbhost1 --user=$dbuser1 --password=$dbpass1; mysqldump --opt --databases $dbname2 --host=$dbhost1 --user=$dbuser1 --password=$dbpass1; mysqldump --opt --databases $dbname3 --host=$dbhost2 --user=$dbuser2 --password=$dbpass2; mysqldump --opt --databases $dbname4 --host=$dbhost2 --user=$dbuser2 --password=$dbp) | gzip > backupfile.sql.gz
```

Comment: @slm : thx for the edit, but he asked for one line ;D

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that the zipped file only contains `backupfile.sql`. Is it possible that the contents of `backupfile.sql.gz` are the individual dumps where the name is `$dbhost.$dbname.sql`? So in my example, `backupfile.sql.gz` should contain `$dbhost1.$dbname1.sql`, `$dbhost1.$dbname2.sql`, `$dbhost2.$dbname3.sql` and `$dbhost2.$dbname4.sql`

Comment: @arvinsim: no.  I recommend you read up on the concepts behind gzip & bzip2; unlike zip they don't produce an archive of a number of files, they compress files individually. Plus this request is orthogonal to your initial question.

Comment: I see, so it is not possible with gzip only. Might be better to tar then gzip.